# Detect when file can't be created because of bad characters in name

Tags: java, windows, filenames

Can anyone tell me how to cope with illegal file names in java? When I run the following on Windows:

```
File badname = new File("C:\\Temp\\a:b");

System.out.println(badname.getAbsolutePath()+" length="+badname.length());

FileWriter w = new FileWriter(badname);
w.write("hello world");
w.close();

System.out.println(badname.getAbsolutePath()+" length="+badname.length());
```

The output shows that the file has been created and has the expected length, but in C:\Temp all I can see is a file called "a" with 0 length. Where is java putting the file?

What I'm looking for is a reliable way to throw an error when the file can't be created. I can't use exists() or length() - what other options are there?

Answer (score 2):

In that particular example, the data is being written to a [named stream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364404%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You can see the data you've written from the command line as follows:

```
 more < .\a:b
```

For information about valid file names, [look here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

To answer your specific question: exists() should be sufficient.  Even in this case, after all, the data *is* being written to the designated location - it just wasn't where you expected it to be!  If you think this case will cause problems for your users, check for the presence of a colon in the file name.

Comment: I've been using Windows for a very long time, and I'd never heard of named streams. I wonder what [architecture astronaut](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000018.html) came up with that?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/). They allow you to break apart a string and see if certain characteristics apply. The other method that would work is splitting the String into a char[], and then processing each point to see what's in it, and if it's legal... but I think RegEx would work much better.

Answer (score 0):

Get the file name first:

```
String fileName = fullPath.substring(fullPath.lastIndexOf('\\'), fullPath.length);
```

Create an array of all special chars not allowed in file names.

for each `char` in array, check if `fileName` contains it. I guess, Java has a pre-built API for it.

Check [this.](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0040__Data-Type/ChecksiftheStringcontainsanycharacterinthegivensetofcharacters.htm)

Note: *This solution assumes that parent directory exists*

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) and create a pattern which will match any illegal character, something like this:

```
String fileName = "...";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[:;!?]");
Matcher matcher = pattern.match(fileName);

if (matcher.find())
{
    //Do something when the file name has an illegal character.
}
```

Note: I have not tested this code, but it should be enough to get you on the right track. The above code will match any string which contains a `:`, `;`, `!' and '?'. Feel free to add/remove as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `File.renameTo(File dest);`.